# If we create an object called 'a' from a function constructor, then why is 'a' not an instance of Function?

Tags: javascript, function, function-constructor

```js
function person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}
var myFather = new person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
console.log(myFather instanceof person); //true
console.log(myFather instanceof Object); //true
console.log(myFather instanceof Function); //false
```

Hello, in this case, we created an object from the function constructor: 'person'.

Every function in JavaScript is an instance of the Function constructor. 
Why is myFather not an instance of Function?

Comment: Because the object referenced by `myFather` is a plain object *created* by the `person()` constructor. When you call a function with `new`, a new object is created and bound to `this` in the constructor context.

Comment: The prototype chain is myFather -> person.prototype -> object.prototype . instanceof checks for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myFather` is an object instance of `person` that is why it is returning true for `myFather instanceof Object` but false for `myFather instanceof Function` as it is not a function but an object, you can't call myFather again to instantiate another object. Actually `person` is an instance of Function. When you call `new person` a plain object is returned and it is stored in myFather.

```js
function person(first, last, age, eye) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eye;
}
var myFather = new person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
console.log(myFather instanceof person); //true
console.log(myFather instanceof Object); //true
console.log(myFather instanceof Function); //false
console.log(person instanceof Function); //true
```

Comment: ah ok, I got it now. Thanks a lot